# What's the easiest way to trim out values from XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, altova

I have an XML document that have additonal nodes in it at different levels that I want to remove via XSLT.

My intuition is to generate an XSD (using Altova or the like), remove the elements I don't want to appear in my output, then let the editor (Altova or the like) auto generate an XSLT to transform the old XSD into the new XSD.

Back in the day, I used to write XSL for this by hand...but with all these cool tools, is there really a reason to or can someone suggest an alternative way? I haven't done this stuff in a couple of years, so I figured I would ask...

I ended up coming up with this, which is pretty simple, so thanks for the suggestion:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" >
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template xpath-default-namespace="http://www.tempuri.org" match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template xpath-default-namespace="http://www.tempuri.org" match="SomeNode">
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template xpath-default-namespace="http://www.tempuri.org" match="TheNode[@type!='SomeType' and @type!='OtherType']">
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The one remaining thing I need to do is check for a missing element "SomeSubElement" of "TheNode" and insert an empty element if it's missing.

Any suggestions on how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: As far as reasons go, it's probably faster to write the XSLT than the XSD...

Comment: First, that's another question. You should ask again. Second, that isn't the way to deal with QNames: put just one `xpath-default-namespace="http://www.tempuri.org"` in the `stylesheet` root element, or put a namespace declaration `xmlns:temp="http://www.tempuri.org"` in the `stylesheet` root element and use a full QName in patterns like `temp:SomeNode`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple identity transform with empty templates for what you want to discard:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  version="2.0">

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="tagToBeRemoved"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I can't seem to get my tags to be removed to be respected. I have   <xsl:template match="/MyRoot"/>. I've also tried as   <xsl:template match="MyRoot"/>. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JeffN825: If you're still having difficulties, edit your post to include some sample XML input and the empty templates in your XSLT that aren't working.

Comment: @JeffN825: Maybe there is some namespace declarations?